# How to get an updated github repo

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a github repo, and since then the original repo has been updated.  How do I get "clone" the new repo?

I am pretty sure deleting the old repo on my local and then re-cloning, is the wrong way to do this.

Also, I have not made any changes to original clone, so I am not worried about losing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made no changes to the original, a simple `git pull` should update your local repo.

If you are new to git maybe this will help: http://de.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html

Comment: would it bit 'git pull origin master' from the root directory?  Also, the image from the link is helpful.  Thanks

Comment: i assume that the branch has not changed, so just do `git pull` without more parameters